# Getting the returned value from a fetch call

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to call an endpoint in an api that returns a value, I have a dream to call this fetch function inside another function, then save it to a variable.

But this returns a promise or if I get it working the function calls other things before the returned value.

Is the only way to do a timeout?

Here is a code example

```
async function someFetch() {
  const res = await fetch("someurl");
  const data = res.json();
  return data;
}

function useFetched(someInput1, someInput2) {
  const fetchedData = someFetch(); // need this input before anything else is called

  const some_var = fetchedData + someInput1 + someInput2;

  return some_var;
}
```

I've also tried to make the second function async and called await in front of someFetch(), but this returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need need to `await` the result of `someFetch`

```
async function useFetched(someInput1, someInput2){
    const fetchedData = await someFetch() // need this input before anything else is called

    const some_var = fetchedData + someInput1 + someInput2

    return some_var
}
```

Comment: Worked if instead of returning some_var I called a function that handles the value, instead of returning.

Comment: No, it's just some dummy code for a backend call. Basically the idea was to call the backend for a return value (the backend calls another api and does some calculations). Then the next functions do some calculations, and is then called by a third function. Therefor returning a value, but the fix was to call the function inside the second function with the variables, instead of returning an object which is handled elsewhere.

Comment: The proper way is to use either `async await` or `.then` on `useFetched` too. But if you got it working,  good job?

Comment: I asked if it was react because the second answer has `useEffect` and stuf inside it, which got me  confused

Answer (score 0):

You cant make async useFetch`[hook]`. You need to use a callback here. The rough idea, you can pass setter function to `useFetch` to set value. And then can use that value.

**Sample:**

```
async function fetchTodo() {
  const res = await fetch("someurl");
  const data = res.json();
  return data;
}

function useFetched(id, callback) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodo(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      callback(data);
    });
  }, [id, callback]);
}
```

**Working sample:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
async function fetchTodo(id) {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + id);
  const data = res.json();
  return data;
}

function useFetched(id, callback) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodo(id).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      callback(data);
    });
  }, [id, callback]);
}
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useFetched(1, setData);
  if (!data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-smoke-ls2y4?file=/src/App.js:0-607